# Inverse of $I-A$ if $A^2 = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I got this problem for linear algebra class.

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. Show that if $A^2=\mathbf{0}$ then $\mathbf{I}-A$ is
nonsingular and $(\mathbf{I}-A)^{-1}= \mathbf{I} + A$.

Comment: To show that $I-A$ is an inverse of $I+A$, consider multiplying them together and see what you get.  And the existence of an inverse implies a matrix is nonsingular.

Comment: What I would add to the comment by @KyleMiller is that you should check both $(I - A)(I + A)$ and $(I + A)(I - A)$.  Remember that matrix multiplication is not necessarily commutative (i.e., for two matrices $A$ and $B$, we **don't** necessarily have $AB = BA$, so that's why you need to check both products.  If both products equal the identity $I$, then $I + A$ and $I - A$ are inverses of each other.

Comment: For square matrices, left and right inverses are the same, so (if this fact is known) we don't need to check both products.

Comment: It's occasionally useful to recall that the formal inverse of $I - A$ is $I + A + A^2 + \cdots$, and in particular if $A^n = 0$, then the (bona fide) inverse of $A$ is $I + A + \cdots + A^{n - 1}$.

Answer (score 2):

$(\mathbf{I}-A)(\mathbf{I}+A)=\mathbf{I}^2-A^2=\mathbf{I}$

Since a matrix $B$ is non-singular if and only if there exists a matrix $C$ such that $BC=\mathbf{I}$, and that matrix is unique, it follows that $(\mathbf{I}-A)^{-1}=\mathbf{I}+A$.

Answer (score 1):

- What is $(I-A)(I + A)$ ?
- What do you know about uniqueness of the inverse?

If you answer these questions you should be able to figure this out.